# Trigonometric ratios of compound angles

Tags: trigonometry

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be two different roots of equation $a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta=c$, prove that $\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\dfrac{2ab}{a^2+b^2}$

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927530/cosine-of-the-sum-of-two-solutions-of-trigonometric-equation-a-cos-theta-b-s

Comment: The method of posting the Question is almost identical to that of the Related Question. Then I'm not sure why this Question has been down-voted?

Answer (score 0):

We're given

$$a\cos\alpha+b\sin\alpha=c=a\cos\beta+b\sin\beta\implies a(\cos\alpha-\cos\beta)+b(\sin\alpha-\sin\beta)=0\stackrel{\text{trig. identites}}\iff$$

$$-2a\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}2+2b\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}2\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}2=0\iff$$

$$\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}2\left(b\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}2-a\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\right)=0\implies$$

$$\tan\frac{\alpha+\beta}2=\frac ba$$

Use a little trigonometric identities ( say,

$$\;1+\tan^2x=\frac1{\cos^2x}\;,\;\;\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x\;,\;\;\sin x=2\sin\frac x2\cos\frac x2\;)$$  to deduce that from the above follows what you want.

Comment: This method is closely related to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927530/cosine-of-the-sum-of-two-solutions-of-trigonometric-equation-a-cos-theta-b-s/927540#927540 (See my comment in the Question)

Comment: Yes @labbhattacharjee, it's similar...but I never heard these identities being called that way.

Comment: Have you meant Prosthaphaeresis (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)?

Comment: Yup @labbhattacharjee , that . I've only known them as some trigonometric identites, which btw follow at once from other, more basic, ontes.

Comment: I've found many such ascription here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/topics/TrigonometricIdentities.html

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** introduce the angle $\kappa \in \Bbb R / 2\pi \Bbb Z $ such as
$$
\sin \kappa = \frac b{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\\
\cos \kappa = \frac a{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}\\
$$

This ways the property to prove reads
$$
\sin (\alpha + \beta) = 2\sin\kappa \cos\kappa
$$