# If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the solutions of $a\cos \theta+ b\sin \theta= c$ show that

Tags: trigonometry

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the solutions of $a\cos \theta+ b\sin \theta= c$ show that

1) $\sin \alpha + \sin \beta = \dfrac{2bc}{a^2 + b^2}$

2) $\sin \alpha \sin \beta = \dfrac{c^2-a^2}{a^2+b^2}$

I couldn't even start the problem, and I generally have a lot of difficulty in compound angles so please help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927530/cosine-of-the-sum-of-two-solutions-of-trigonometric-equation-a-cos-theta-b-s

Answer (score 1):

$$a\cos\theta = c - b\sin\theta \implies a^2\cos^2\theta = c^2-2bc\sin\theta+b^2\sin^2\theta \\ \implies (a^2-a^2\sin^2\theta) = c^2-2bc\sin\theta+b^2\sin^2\theta $$

> $$(a^2+b^2)\sin^2\theta - (2bc)\sin\theta+(c^2-a^2)=0 \equiv Ax^2 + Bx +C = 0$$

As $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the solutions of the given equation, $\sin\alpha \equiv x_1$ and $\sin\beta \equiv x_2$ satisfy the above equation.

If $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the solutions of $Ax^2 + Bx +C = 0$, then ,

$$x_1+x_2 = -\frac{B}{A} \implies \sin\alpha + \sin\beta = - \frac{-2bc}{a^2+b^2} = \frac{2bc}{a^2+b^2}$$

and

$$x_1 \cdot x_2 = \frac{C}{A} \implies \sin\alpha\cdot\sin\beta=\frac{c^2-a^2}{a^2+b^2}$$

Comment: If alpha and beta are solutions of the equation, then how did you take x1 and x2 as sin alpha and beta?

Comment: I just used it as an equivalence to the quadratic equation,

Comment: Didn’t know we can do that. Could u elaborate on that?

Comment: If we have a quadratic equation $$Ax^2+Bx+ C = 0 \implies x = \frac{-B\pm\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}$$ Now the sum of the roots is $$x_1 + x_2 =  \frac{-B+\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A}+ \frac{-B-\sqrt{B^2-4AC}}{2A} = -\frac{B}{A}$$ and their product is $$x_1x_2 = \frac{-B^2-(B^2-4AC)}{4A^2} = \frac{C}{A}$$ Here replace $x = \sin\theta$, $x_1 = \sin\alpha$ and $x_2 = \sin\beta$

Comment: That’s true, but what I am still confused about is, alpha and beta are the roots of the equation, not sin alpha and sin beta. So how can we just use them interchangeably